# How to fix fonts in Firefox Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox, fonts

Sometime ago when I installed Windows 7 I played around with settings and I knew I changed some settings that affected the font on Firefox. In a few websites, few fonts look weird, it was quite manageable so I didn't mind it. However in other websites, almost all of the font looks weird like this:

[image]

Try viewing the image in full screen to see what I mean

How can I fix this?

Comment: You did press ctrl+0 to reset zoom already, right? If you didn't, try that now.

Comment: The fonts do look wrong there, almost "bitmap" like.  Can you recall anything about the setting you messed with?

Comment: @esalaka yup, didn't work, I don't think it's a zoom issue.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that's the problem, I don't recall it since it took a while before I noticed that fonts were looking weird. And it only happens on a occasional websites that I visit, for example fonts look fine here at superuser.com

Comment: Ok I think I solved the problem on that particular website by using the default ClearType Text Tuner in Windows 7, however, it caused problems in other websites like Gmail (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ZHrZf.png as well as Superuser (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/fNUgj.png)

BTW the Windows 7 ClearType Text Tuner is very hard to use, there are a lot of choices, and it is so hard to find the perfect settings since the choices look very similar.

Comment: As it appears other users have similar problems like this one: http://superuser.com/questions/331438/fonts-in-firefox-look-bad

However, as I've searched none of the solutions solves mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I found an answer to my own question.
After long research I finally found a solution in this site:
http://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/23/blurry-fonts-in-firefox-try-anti-aliasing-tuner/

I did not use the Anti Aliasing Tuner though, what I did was simply disable Hardware acceleration.

[image]

I hope this helps someone in the future.