# Mozilla Firefox anti-aliasing different on different systems?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, fonts

I have a laptop and a desktop PC, both running Windows Home Premium. Mozilla Firefox is the default browser.

The thing is, the anti-aliasing / font-smoothing in Firefox is pretty good on my desktop PC, and kinda rough in the Firefox on my laptop.

**Website I tested:** [aahank.com](http://aahank.com/)

**Screenshots:**

<sub>**Click on the image to enlarge**</sub>

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Versus...**

[image: Screenshot 2]

Notice the difference? I use the same addons on both Firefoxes. Any idea what could be causing the font-smoothing difference?

**More Info:**

✔ [**Use hardware acceleration when available**](https://superuser.com/a/349645/94039) — option is checked in both browsers.

✔ [**Adjust ClearType text**](https://superuser.com/a/453986/94039) — settings checked. Both have the same.

✔ Both systems have the **font ([Open Sans](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Open+Sans)) installed locally**. Same quality `ttf` files.

Comment: Do you found a solution? I have the same problem but nothing works.

Comment: @Scoutman No, I haven't found any solution either.

Answer (score 1):

In about:config, check the settings for `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params` and compare them between your desktop and laptop.

<sup><sub>Source: [DirectWrite Text Rendering in Firefox 6](http://blog.mozilla.org/nattokirai/2011/08/11/directwrite-text-rendering-in-firefox-6/)</sub></sup>

[image: gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params]

> These are effectively **local overrides of ClearType registry settings** that are set by running the ClearType tuner tool (Control Panels > Fonts > ClearType Text Settings).

I didn't get to test these configurations because I don't have Mozilla Firefox on Windows 7 at the moment, but judging from that article, it looks like this may be the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Again, they are just the same. :(

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works on my computer.

In **about:config** set:

```
gfx.direct2d.force-enabled = true
```

More information are here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Blocklisting/Blocked_Graphics_Drivers

Answer (score 0):

**Adjust your ClearType settings.**

> ClearType is a software technology developed by Microsoft that improves the readability of text on existing LCDs (Liquid Crystal Displays), such as laptop screens, Pocket PC screens and flat panel monitors. With ClearType font technology, the words on your computer screen look almost as sharp and clear as those printed on a piece of paper.

1. In Windows Explorer, go to "**Control Panel\Appearance and
   Personalization\Display**".
2. On the left sidebar, click "**Adjust ClearType text**".
3. If you want to have the same ClearType output on both computers, you can compare the settings of both your Windows 7 computers.

[image]

Comment: Was just about to add that to my question. Done this already. Doesn't change anything. Thanks though. :)