# How can I turn on antialiasing in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, anti-aliasing

I hope this is the correct place to ask a question like this.

Recently, my Firefox (39.0 on Windows Seven) stopped antialiasing texts.

http://www.mindoki.com/tmp/ffaliasing.png

(I provide links instead of uploading to the site as it seems it's a bit antialiased if I do).

On IE it is perfectly okay and looks like this:

http://www.mindoki.com/tmp/IEantialiasing.png

I have searched for some parameter in the options but have found nothing that seems relevant.

How can I resolve this?

[EDIT] If you edit, Please DON'T add the images because (as I already stated), they get antialiased on the site!

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by aliasing?

Comment: I'm sure this is caused by antialiasing isn't present. If you look closely (zoom in a lot), the first image has only black and white pixels, the second one have a whole range of gray colors.

Comment: related: [this](http://superuser.com/questions/563793/how-do-i-disable-font-anti-aliasing-in-firefox-while-keeping-font-hinting-on), [this](http://superuser.com/questions/453967/mozilla-firefox-anti-aliasing-different-on-different-systems) and [that](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1002008)

Comment: Hah, I earned the badge for "popular question" on this one. Question + correct answer, neither appreciated at all it seems!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like cleartype is disabled. Search for cleartype in windows search in your start menu, and verify that cleartype is turned on.

Comment: Hey man that did the trick! I guess I accidentally disabled cleartypes when I messed with optimisations (removing those annoying window zoom-dezoom stuffs and so), thanks!